# How to set default save type in Excel to match template?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

If I create a new workbook by double-clicking a macro-enabled template, say **standardform.xltm**, I will get a new file called **standardform1**.

When I go to Save (Save As...), I am prompted to save it as a standard Excel Workbook (**standarform1.xltx**), which will strip out the macros on save.

Is there a way to make new documents created from a macro-enabled template default to saving as macro-enabled workbooks (.xltm)?

Comment: Does the template contain some macros ? Is [macro security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-macro-security-settings-in-excel-a97c09d2-c082-46b8-b19f-e8621e8fe373) set to low?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA macro that I found in the article
[How to force users to save as a macro enabled workbook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4416-excel-force-save-as-macro-enabled.html)

This macro will force a Save As dialog with `.xlsm` as the default type:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'Updateby Extendoffice
Dim xFileName As String
If SaveAsUI <> False Then
    Cancel = True
    xFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As xlsm file")
    If xFileName <> "False" Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
      Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
      MsgBox "Action Cancelled"
      Cancel = True
      Exit Sub
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

See the article for detailed instructions with screenshots on how to
install the macro in the template file.

Comment: This *almost* works.  It breaks some of the functionality of the Recent Places in the Save As dialog in 365.  It forces you to start from Documents and browse from there in a standard file dialog.

Comment: You might prefer `FileDialog` over `GetSaveAsFilename`. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165166/165358).

Answer (score 0):

Have you file> Options then save and select the format you want.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: My question is not about how to save the document myself.  My question is how to give this *.xltm* template to other users and require them to save new documents created with it as *.xlsm*.  The typical user is quite puzzled by the dialog warning them about features that cannot be saved in a macro-free workbook.  They just click Yes, which saves as a macro-free workbook and strips out the macros. The workbook will not function on next open.